# Prove: $n-1$ linearly independent equations define a one dimensional vector space in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, systems-of-equations

Prove: $n-1$ linearly independent equations define a one dimensional vector space in $\mathbb{R}^n$ .
Basically, I want to prove that given a set of  $n-1$ linearly independent equations in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a set of points that adhere to those equations, that the set of points all have to be in the same one dimensional vector space in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I want to solve this algebraically, and I think there just has to be a way to do this with the rank-nullity theorem but I can't really figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty lightly, $n-1$ linearly independent equations means the solution is a strict $x_1, x_2, x_3, ..., x_{n-1}$ values that solve the system, leaving $x_n$ as the free variable which has no affect on the solution..., defining the solution on a one-dimensional vector space.

In other words, expressing your system of equations in an augmented matrix of $Ax = \vec{b}$ means that the null space is $1$ dimensional (all linearly independent, except for $x_n$). Reducing this matrix will yield leading coefficients on $x_1, ..., x_2, x_3, x_3, x_{n-1}$ and define a 1 dimensional vector space solution after parametrized. The rank of the matrix is strictly $n-1$, so you'll be left with $1$ free variable that won't affect your solution. Using the rank-nullity theorem, then $im(A)$ has some solution set $x_1, x_2, ..., Ax = b$ and adding any linear combination of the remaining null space will not affect the solution...since $An = 0, n \in \text{null}(A)$.

Note that this is **only** true if indeed the system of equations is solvable...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just wanted to follow up: If I define a point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ by $n$ equations, is there a way to explain the fact that if 2 points share $n-1$ linearly independent equations, then they are both in the same one dimensional vector space?

Comment: I'm a bit confused from your question from "if 2 points share $n-1$ linearly independent equations". Do you mean if there are 2 points that satisfy the linear system, then they are both in the same one dimensional vector space?

Comment: Yeah. I don't see how you can use the nullity theorem to prove that directly.

Comment: ...If they're not in the same one dimensional vector space...then the first point will be in some one dimensional space that satisfies $Ax = b$ and the second one will be in another one dimensional space that satisfies $Ax' = b$...so any linear combination of the two solutions,  $\frac{1}{2}x + \frac{1}{2}x'$ is also a solution...which is two dimensional, x from the first space, x' from the second space..and this is a contradiction since we only required $1$ dimensional and asserted that there were $n - 1$ linear independent equations.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help !